# How to get the scoped attributes when creating a new object through a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When creating objects through a `has_many` association like `User.first.books.create!(...)`, the new book gets the `user_id` automatically from the association.

Is there any way to get that `user_id` if I call my own create method? i.e. `User.first.books.own_create_method`

```
def self.own_create_method
  # how to get the user object?
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging into ActiveRecord `new` method, I found that you can call `scope_attributes` and you'll get a hash with all the attributes that are scoped.

```
def self.own_create_method
   attributes = scope_attributes
   # attributes["user_id"] would be the user_id that is scoped by
   ...
end
```

Not sure if this is a good practice though...

Answer (score 0):

To define `User.first.books.own_create_method` you would use:

```
def self.own_create_method
  book = build
  # something custom you want to do with book
  book.save
end
```

`self.` allows you to define class methods in Ruby.

Comment: He wants to get ``user_id`` in the method though.